# Creating a new command that keeps track of numbers and their order for math definitions

Tags: numbering

I am trying to create a new command that signals the introduction of a definition. Below is a minimum working example, but I want to add some functionality to the new command so that it keeps track of the definition numbers automatically and in order as they are produced. As it is right now, if I were to compress two definitions, I would need to manually change every number in \defn{}. I know LaTeX has this functionality, but being relatively new to the language, I don't exactly know where to find what I am after.

I think a more optimal solution would be that I can just write `\defn` and then it would keep track of everything, but the tracking aspect is what I don't fully understand so far as the implementation.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[left=0.5in,right=0.5in, bottom=0.5in, top =0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mdframed} % Creates boxes around theorem statements. 


% Add new commands:
\newcommand{\defn}[1]{\textbf{D#1:}} % Instead of using bold, it'll be clear to use defn as definition. 


\begin{document}

\defn{1}

\defn{2}

\defn{3}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typically done using counters. For every `\newcounter{<cntr>}`, LaTeX creates `\the<cntr>` that acts like the representation of the counter. Since you're using a **D** presentation, I've redefined `\thedefn` to be `D\arabic{defn}`. `\refstepcounter{defn}` allows you to properly `\label` and `\ref`erence content as well.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{defn}
\renewcommand{\thedefn}{D\arabic{defn}}

% Add new commands:
\newcommand{\defn}{%
  \par\noindent
  \refstepcounter{defn}%
  \textbf{\thedefn:}~\ignorespaces%
}

\begin{document}

\defn Here is some definition.

\defn \label{def:two}This is another definition.

\defn The final definition. See definition~\textbf{\ref{def:two}}.

\end{document}
```